# Disable Algorithm Key

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-graphs

I guess it is a rather simple question:  Is it possible to disable or unselect an algorithm in the graph-drawing library?

---

The reason for this is that I am defining a command that uses the `\graph` command which sets up a lot of defaults and among these defaults is the `spring layout` algorithm.  In some rare cases though, I want to disable this algorithm because the `spring layout` does not allow nodes which are specified outside of the graph to be used.

Since the vast majority of cases use the `spring layout` and only very specific circumstances need that to be disabled, it would be better to avoid unnecessary redundancy by disabling the `spring layout` when I don't need it (as opposed to having to enable it nearly all the time).

If this isn't possible, I can always resolve this by defining starred/unstarred versions of the command.

---

Hereunder is a minimal (and somewhat unnatural) example.  Is it possible to have the `spring layout` key specified and then subsequently removed so that it is as if it was never specified?  The `no layout` nearly does what I want, but Lua still complains that it cannot create edges between nodes that are not specified in the graph.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force,trees}
\begin{document}
% What doesn't work
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0, 0) (a) {a};
  \node [above of=a] (b) {b};
  \node [left of=b] (c) {c};
  \graph [spring layout, no layout] { (a) -- (b) -- (c) };
\end{tikzpicture}
% What it should (ideally) revert back to (as if I never specified spring layout)
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \node at (0, 0) (a) {a};
  \node [above of=a] (b) {b};
  \node [left of=b] (c) {c};
  \graph { (a) -- (b) -- (c) };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can't you just not use that layout? What do you mean by an `alias`? Can you give an example of what you are doing and why it is causing problems?

Comment: By an alias, I mean that I have basically `\def\mygraph{\graph [blah]}`, but somewhat more complicated.  I *could* just not use that layout, but the whole point of this is that 95% of the time, I will be using the `spring layout`.

Comment: Sorry, but I really don't understand what you are trying to do. What I meant was, in those cases when you don't want that layout, don't use it with your alias just as you wouldn't use it with `\graph`. When you do want it, obviously use it. Clearly your alias *itself* can't know when you do or don't want it. You have to tell it. How else can it know? As I say, an example would no doubt make this clearer, even if a certain muddiness remained. Right now, I really don't have any idea what you are trying to do. If you are using LaTeX, you are better using `\newcommand` than `\def`.

Comment: I don't see how my initial question is not clear:  Can you disable `spring layout` after having specified it.  Anyway, the command is something like:
`\def\mygraph{\pgfutil@ifnextchar[}{\mygraph@opt}{\mygraph@opt[]}` and 
`\def\mygraph@opt[#1]{\graph [define defaults, how to handle unknown keys, change default search paths, #1]}`
It is slightly more than an alias.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It is easier to help you if you add a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/) that takes the form `\documentclass{...}\usepackage{....}\begin{document}...\end{document}`. If possible, it should compile and have the *minimum* amount of code needed to illustrate your problem. This makes it much easier for people to troubleshoot your problem - and much more likely that they will! In this instance, there is little hope that people will be able to guess the custom macros (aliases) that you are using without seeing the code.

Answer (score 2):

Specifying another layout will override any existing layout. Alternatively the `no layout` can be used:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=5]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{graphs,graphdrawing}
\usegdlibrary{force,trees}
\begin{document}
\tikz\path 
 (0,0) [text=red]   graph [spring layout]              {A -> {B -> {C, D}, E}}
 (2,0) [text=green] graph [spring layout, no layout]   {A -> {B -> {C, D}, E}}
 (4,0) [text=blue]  graph [spring layout, tree layout] {A -> {B -> {C, D}, E}};
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That looked really promising, but unfortunately it still uses Lua the draw the graph which doesn't support nodes defined outside the graph.  I have updated the original post to give a minimal example.

Comment: @Josh yes, you're right. Unfortunately, I can't see any way around it.